# Getting "error": "invalid_grant" while accessing the /token endpoint of oidc

Tags: openid-connect

While hitting the OIDC /token endpoint with Authorization_code Grant type , facing **""error"**: **"invalid_grant"** error. With **"error_description"**: **"grant request is invalid"**

The `/auth` endpoint is working fine as I am able to generate the code.

Tried through postman, with the following curl command.

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8000/token \
  -H 'authorization: Basic dGVzdF9vYXV0aF9hcHA6c3VwZXJfc2VjcmV0' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'postman-token: 758ae0e0-26fd-20e5-d4fe-cff3f5432b32' \
  -d 'grant_type=authorization_code&scope=openid%20&code=68498567-4623-4d80-a1c2-27f5bbc2c087&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Ftestapp%2Fsignin-oidc'
```

Expecting the "token" in response.

Comment: Try removing space (%20) in scope paramter the URL encoding. Wrong : scope=openid%20 , Assumed go be correct : scope=openid